# Removing Stains Off Denim

Tags: cleaning, clothing, after-wash

I just got my black denim jeans back from the laundry and unfortunately it seems white stains have developed all over then.

I've tried washing them out with plain water however that doesn't seem to work.

Is there another way of removing white stains off denim?

Comment: Sure it's actually stained... or bleached? White on black would have to be something solidly white, like toothpaste [which of course would come off easily] or paint... which wouldn't.

Comment: I find if I wash black jeans right-side-out they get white stripes where the machine has abraded the surface. Always wash jeans wrong-side-out. Anyway, if this is the case, dye them black again. Works wonders.

Answer (score 3):

Toothpaste causes stains in clothes because it contains titanium dioxide. It can't get out unless there's a detergent.

Spot clean with some diluted detergent and a cloth for best results. Make sure the stain is out before putting the garment in a dryer, as high temperatures can ‘set’ stains.

Comment: The question doesn't mention toothpaste.

Answer (score 1):

Combine water and a teaspoon of salt. Dip a rag into the mix. Scrub the stain of the denim with the rug, until the stain has vanished. Leave the denim out to dry for a half hour. Complete.

Comment: "Combine water with a teaspoon of salt" means nothing if the amount of water is not specified.

Comment: I would suggest a cup or so of water

Comment: Did this work @TheMan